# How do I hide the GPU from one tf::Session() in a multi-session scenario?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have a C++ program that makes use of two different classifiers running in separate `tensorflow::Session`s. One of these models needs to run on the GPU, while the second is very small and I'd like for it to run on the CPU.

I tried creating the sessions using:

```
auto options = tensorflow::SessionOptions();
options.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction(0);
m_session.reset(tensorflow::NewSession(options));
```

but this seems only to trigger the default "hog the GPU" behaviour.

I also tried playing around with `options.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_visible_device_list("-1")` but there is a specific check in the TF code for invalid devices in the list that raises an error.

Setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` in the environment before running the program is of course not an option because the GPU should be visible for the session that needs it.

Does anyone know how to forbid *just one* one session to use the GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy workaround would be to temporarily set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` using `putenv("CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1");` and reset it after creating the session.

```
std::string str_tmp = "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=";
str_tmp += getenv("CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES");
putenv("CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1");

#Create session

#Reset environment variable
putenv(str_tmp);
```

However, there might be a cleaner way to do it without changing your environment variables.

Comment: Somehow it did not occur to me that I don't necessarily need to keep the environment variables as they were at program startup... Thanks, I do hope there is a better way out there but this is already a step in the right direction

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this. I did not try whether the `+=` works but I suspect it might crash when `getenv` returns a nullptr (if the env var doesn't exist). 
I tried doing `std::string tmp = getenv(...)` and that crashed on nullptr, so I believe `+=` would do the same.